# How to prompt user to open a browser instance as a different windows logged in User

Tags: c#, google-chrome, authentication, windows-authentication

I have web application **A** using **windows authentication** and Web application **B** using **windows authentication**. Application B can be accessed through Application A only via links.

Now I sign in as a different user in Application A and click on a link which navigates to Application B. But Application B still uses the old user.

Is there a way to prompt the end user to login to use different browser instance completely.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make the URL of the new page be a domain that isn't Intranet (or doesn't have some form of SSO)

Comment: Thanks Ed. But these are fully developed applications and should work on the intranet.

Comment: Then the only option is to hold shift, Right Click the application and Run As Different User.